# How to copy symlinks to target as normal folders

Tags: linux, symbolic-link, command-line, cp

i have a folder with symlinks:

```
marek@marek$ ls -al /usr/share/solr/
razem 36
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2010-11-30 08:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 358 root root 12288 2010-11-26 12:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2010-11-24 14:29 admin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 2010-11-24 14:29 conf -> /etc/solr/conf
```

i want to copy it to ~/solrTest but i want to copy files from symlink as well

when i try to `cp -r /usr/share/solr/ ~/solrTest`

i will have symlink here:

```
marek@marek$ ls -al ~/solrTest
razem 36
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  4096 2010-11-30 08:25 .
drwxr-xr-x 358 root root 12288 2010-11-26 12:25 ..
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root  4096 2010-11-24 14:29 admin
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    14 2010-11-24 14:29 conf -> /etc/solr/conf
```

Answer (score 148):

```
cp -Lr /usr/share/solr/ ~/solrTest
```

Check the `man` page for unix commands with `man cp`

```
   -L, --dereference
          always follow symbolic links in SOURCE
```

Comment: I get "cp: the -H, -L, and -P options may not be specified with the -r option."

Comment: @balupton: try -LR

Comment: if you are on a mac and have the `coreutils` package installed (`brew list coreutils`), you may use `-Lr`. However, `-LR` works universally, so is a better choice for scripts.

You can check which `cp` you have with `man cp | tail -n1`, e.g. a system without GNU coreutils: `BSD    February 23, 2005    BSD` and a system with GNU coreutils: `macOS 13.3    February 23, 2022    macOS 13.3`

Answer (score 15):

From man page:

> ‘-L’ ,‘--dereference’ - Follow symbolic links when copying from them. With this option, cp cannot create a symbolic link. For example, a symlink (to regular file) in the source tree will be copied to a regular file in the destination tree.

So this is the option you should try.

Answer (score 7):

```
cp -r -L /usr/share/solr/ ~/solrTest
```

From the `cp(1)` man page:

> `-L`, `--dereference`
>
> always follow symbolic links in SOURCE

Answer (score 0):

One quick solution is to:

```
$ mkdir dest_dir
$ cp symlink_dir/* dest_dir/
```

the drawback is that you have to create the destination directory first

Comment: In some shells, this won't copy hidden files/folders from `symlink_dir`.