# Unix shell script - cp -R doesn't copy contents behind symbolic links

Tags: macos, unix, shell, shell-script

I've got this `./image` folder full of symbolic links to "real" folders. These "real" folder contain a series of images.

```
./image/stones -> somefolder/stones
./images/grass -> someotherfolder/grass
(etc.)
```

I try to run a script that will copy the contents of these folders from the `./image` folder.

```
mkdir ../SCALE50

for dir in *; do

    echo $dir
    cp -R $dir/ ../SCALE50/$dir

done
```

the problem reported by command line is that

```
arch/*: Not a directory
```

I've almost no experience with command line, but I understand I should say "follow each symbolic link and copy the contents of that folder to the specified location".

Can't find how to phrase that in google. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Do you use bash? Do you want to copy each sub-directory? (as I changed your question)

Comment: I've flagged your question as exact duplicate, sorry :) The answer is here: http://superuser.com/q/216919/3374

Comment: Hi, well it's the macos shell.

Comment: I'm trying to simply do: cp -L ./stones  ../stones_as_folder to copy the folder pointed to by the "stones" symbolic link, but I end up with a copy of the symbolic link

Comment: I'm actually **surprised**. This is actually **a really old** question being revived. @week should get a badge for this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`rsync` is what you need, look at parameters, you want `-r` recursive and `--copy-links` to copy destination file/dir instead of link.