# File Operations Using Symlink Source/Destination

Tags: linux, bash, symbolic-link

I've created a set of symlinks which I can use in BASH with CDPATH:
'desk' which points to my desktop, and 'docs' which points to my documents. I can `cd` using these symlinks `cd docs` without problems, however I'd also like to use these symlinks for file operations (`cp, mv`).

I've read [How to copy symlinks to target as normal folders](https://superuser.com/q/216919/65216), but that doesn't seem to work for me. For example doing `cp -L test.txt docs` simply creates a new folder 'docs' and copies the file there. How can I use these symlinks as shorthand for source and destination?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use the CDPATH environment variable to achieve this, as per the answer [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/45893/open-a-file-using-cdpath-and-symlink) at the Unix & Linux StackExchange site where you have a much better chance of getting good answers to questions related to Unix and Linux.

The answer there though gives some idea of how to circumvent this.